# Xbox 360 doesn't recognize a preconfigured USB stick

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I bought a 16GB USB flash drive for GTA V, and configuring/installing works as expected. But everytime I turn off my console and turn it on again, something goes wrong.

My Xbox says it needs to configure the USB stick again, (as if it is an empty USB stick), of course meaning I have to reinstall GTA V again.

If I plug the USB into my computer however, the USB stick is full, and I can see a lot of hidden files on it.

Has anybody else experienced this problem? Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: Try turning the xbox on with it (the flashdrive) out of the console, then plug it in, does it still have the same issue? Formatting to FAT32 and recreating the file structure each time can cause damage to the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with mine. I think I may have sorted it out.

What you should do is after you've finished playing, don't immediately switch off your console. First go to system settings, then storage and select the USB with the Y button and clear the cache.

Also before you switch the console back on, remove the USB and plug it back in when you're at the home page.

I've done this twice and it's worked, so hopefully it solves your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix it straight from your Xbox is to make it a 8gb device.

1. Go to storage on your Xbox 360 then click Y (device options)
2. Remove Xbox 360, then go to customize.
3. Take the bar down to 8gb, then hit A
4. Clear cache and rename it or whatever and its ready to go

I know it sucks that you'll be missing half your space but better than nothing. This might not work in all cases but most of time only half of space is corrupt. If you're looking to get all your space you'll have to do it through a laptop or buy a new one.